# DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.drop_task only if it exists - Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, parallel-processing

In my oracle procedure, I am creating a task for parallel execution.

```
DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.create_task('xyz');
```

At the end of the procedure I am dropping the task as

```
DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.drop_task('xyz');
```

However, is there a easy way to check if the 'xyz' task exists (it could be in any status or may not exist at all) and drop it before a new task with same name is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may query the table `USER_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_TASKS` or `DBA_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_TASKS`  to check if the task exists.

```
SQL> select TASK_NAME,STATUS FROM user_parallel_execute_tasks WHERE TASK_NAME = 'xyz';
TASK_NAME                           |STATUS
--------------------------------------------
xyz                                 |CREATED
```

So, add something like this in your procedure.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO ct
FROM user_parallel_execute_tasks
WHERE task_name = p_task_name;

IF ct > 0 THEN
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.DROP_TASK(p_task_name);
END  IF;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you drop a task that does not exists a `TASK_NOT_FOUND` exception is thrown

```sql
SQL> 
SQL>  exec DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.DROP_TASK('NOTEXIST');

Error starting at line : 3 in command -
BEGIN DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.DROP_TASK('NOTEXIST'); END;
Error report -
ORA-29498: task not found
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_INTERNAL", line 219
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_INTERNAL", line 316
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE", line 100
ORA-06512: at line 1
29498. 00000 -  "task not found" 
*Cause:    The task did not exist.
*Action:   Use an existing task.
```

so you could just drop the task and catch the exception like so

```sql
SQL> begin 
  2     DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.DROP_TASK('NOTEXIST');
  3  exception
  4     WHEN DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.TASK_NOT_FOUND THEN NULL;
  5  END;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```